# Умножение на значение переменной

Tags: javascript

Делаю калькулятор по расчету услуг, возникла сложность с чекбоксами. 
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы значение переменной "bumaga" умножалось на значение переменной "format" либо "format1" (в зависимости от выбора). Как это можно реализовать? В JS не силён.

```
function calc() {
            //получаем ссылку на элемент Select (Бумага)
            var bumaga = document.getElementById("bumaga");
            //получаем ссылку на чекбокс (Формат)
            var format = document.getElementById("format");
            var format1 = document.getElementById("format1");
            //получаем ссылку на элемент span, в него будем писать стоимость дизайна
            var result = document.getElementById("result"); 

            var price = 0;
            price += parseInt(bumaga.options[bumaga.selectedIndex].value);
            price += (format.checked == true) ? parseInt(format.value) : 0;
            price += (format1.checked == true) ? parseInt(format1.value) : 0;

            result.innerHTML = price;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<b><h2>Выберите параметры заказа:</b></h2>
<br>
<b>Бумага:</b><br>
    <select onchange="calc()" id="bumaga">
        <option value="20">Мелованная матовая, 300 гр.</option>
        <option value="50">Мелованный двухсторонний картон, 270 гр.</option>
        <option value="90">Супергладкая, 300 гр.</option>
        <option value="150">Мелованная глянцевая, 300 гр.</option>
    </select><br><br>

<b>Формат:</b><br>
    <input name="format" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="2" id="format" />
        <label for="format">90x50</label><br>
    <input name="format" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="4" id="format1" />
        <label for="format">85x55</label><br><br>

<h3><b>Стоимость тиража: <span id="result">____</span> руб.</b></h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    function calc() {
        var bumaga = document.getElementById("bumaga");
        var format = document.getElementsByName("format");
        var result = document.getElementById("result");

        var price = 0;
        price = parseInt(bumaga.options[bumaga.selectedIndex].value);
        if (format[0].checked == true){
            price = price * parseInt(format[0].value);
        } else if (format[1].checked == true){
            price = price * parseInt(format[1].value)
        }
        result.innerHTML = price;
    }
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<b><h2>Выберите параметры заказа:</b></h2>
<br>
<b>Бумага:</b><br>
<select onchange="calc()" id="bumaga">
    <option value="20">Мелованная матовая, 300 гр.</option>
<option value="50">Мелованный двухсторонний картон, 270 гр.</option>
<option value="90">Супергладкая, 300 гр.</option>
<option value="150">Мелованная глянцевая, 300 гр.</option>
</select><br><br>

<b>Формат:</b><br>
<input name="format" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="2" id="format" />
    <label for="format">90x50</label><br>
<input name="format" type="radio" onchange="calc()" value="4" id="format1" />
    <label for="format">85x55</label><br><br>

<h3><b>Стоимость тиража: <span id="result">____</span> руб.</b></h3>
```

Comment: Хороший, полезный ответ